# PhD without having enough background

Tags: phd, masters, computer-science, career-path

I'm a master degree graduate student from a school of engineers in computer science. I'm so passionated by researches and continuous learning, and i want to do a PhD

However, my master course wasn't too specialized, and thus i don't consider myself having enough knowledge in the field that i want to persue researches in as a PhD

I'm thinking about doing a new Master more specialized in the field that i want to study. Do you think it's necessary to do that or i can enrol in a PhD and discover the field more once enrolled ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you plan to study? Which country?

Comment: you probably need to name your research field.  Otherwise, it's difficult or impossible to judge whether you can pick up a research field.  For example, I check whether a student has the necessary or close enough background before I accept him/her as a PhD student.

Comment: @Buffy i've been studying in Algeria, and now willing to study in Europ, probably in France.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus i want to persue studies in embedded systems, and everything related to that (Robotics, AI)

Comment: @Mssm that's close enough I think.  Have you taken any hardware subjects?  Embedded system is a huge area.  I'm sure there are sub-areas that overlap with CS.  You should be able to pick up these without having to complete another degree.  Only you can judge.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus i was studying embedded system subject, it contained mainly, micro controllers programming using C/C++, and Raspberry PI technology also, and it involved connecting sensors and actuators (motors for example), but for me it was not that sufficient to place myself as a PhD candidate, at least, in my opinion. What do you think ?

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus i also had a subject on electronics, but it was mainly theoritical, and it wasn't that fruitfull

Comment: @Mssm Wow, you cannot do electronics in theory.  That's no good.  It's like a programming language in theory.  What you've described regarding embedded systems is typical of an undergraduate degree.  That should get you some background.  As for others, you will need to learn what to skills you need to carry out your project.  This forum has many questions about doing research and learning what you need to be successful.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus thank you for your opinion, yes i agree i need to learn more. But tell me, do you think i can do that during the first weeks / months of a PhD or should i be ready before starting the PhD ?

Comment: @Mssm Your supervisor(s) should help with that.  What you need to learn is very much dependent on the project.  There is simply too much information in any area.  So you need supervisors who can tell you necessary topics or what to focus on. Otherwise, you'll never finish.

Comment: Hahaha true fact, thank you very much for your help @Prof.SantaClaus